# How to continuously check ltrace command output in C program

Tags: c, ltrace

I'm trying to capture output of `ltrace` command using C program.

I have tried using `popen()` but that's not working, I need to capture continuously output not only once.

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int carg, char *args[]) {
    FILE *fp = popen("ltrace -p pid", "r");
    char buf[255];
    while (1) {
        if (fgets(buf, 255, fp) != NULL) {
            printf("Captured Text: %s", buf);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please give me your advice

Comment: yes that ltrace command is in Linux,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ltrace` outputs to *stderr*, not *stdout*. But [`popen()`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages-dev/popen.3.en.html#DESCRIPTION) will read the pipe connecting the command's *stdout*. So this should be enough to fix it:

```
FILE *fp = popen("ltrace -p pid 2>&1", "r");
```

UPDATE: likewise, to filter directly the same `ltrace` command in a shell:

```
ltrace -p pid 2>&1 | grep someregex
```

`ltrace`'s default output is to *stderr* so it has to be redirected to *stdout* to be useful for a pipe.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much. You made my day. Bravo

Comment: And need one more suggestion please, is it possible use `grep` command on `ltrace` command? I have tried regex on it but didn't work

Comment: same: `ltrace .... 2>&1 | grep ....` . And if you're satisfied with the answer, please to accept it.